# What is the best subversion client for Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, svn, smartsvn

Hello i am new to ios programming,recently i created ios project,i just wanted to share this code with team members,so i tried smartsvn,snailsvn,scplugin none of these are not working fine,scplugin is not compatible with mac osx 10.11 next i tried snailsvn it is working fine but when i take update it is not showing conflicts,similarly smartsvn free version is also not showing conflicts,please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best client is the the command line client. It comes with your mac.
http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.html

I'm not being flippant, I truly do believe it is the best client.  This is opinion, but anything else is only obscuring what's happening.

Comment: It's powerfull; but I'm sure that `smartSVN` is more convenient.